# Fastest way to select objects using other collection in Smalltalk

Tags: optimization, collections, smalltalk

Given two collections:

```
srcCollection := #('Lorem' 'ipsum' 'dolor' 'sit' 'amet,' 'consectetur' 'adipisicing' 'elit,' 'sed' 'do' 'eiusmod' 'tempor' 'incididunt' 'ut' 'labore' 'et' 'dolore' 'magna' 'aliqua.' 'Ut' 'enim' 'ad' 'minim' 'veniam,' 'quis' 'nostrud' 'exercitation' 'ullamco' 'laboris' 'nisi' 'ut' 'aliquip' 'ex' 'ea' 'commodo' 'consequat.' 'Duis' 'aute' 'irure' 'dolor' 'in' 'reprehenderit' 'in' 'voluptate' 'velit' 'esse' 'cillum' 'dolore' 'eu' 'fugiat' 'nulla' 'pariatur.' 'Excepteur' 'sint' 'occaecat' 'cupidatat' 'non' 'proident,' 'sunt' 'in' 'culpa' 'qui' 'officia' 'deserunt' 'mollit' 'anim' 'id' 'est' 'laborum').      
objCollection := #('Lorem' 'numquam' 'eius' 'modi' 'tempora' 'incidunt' 'ut' 'labore' 'et' 'dolore' 'magnam' 'aliquam' 'ipsum' 'dolor' 'ex' 'ea' 'commodo' 'consequat.' 'Duis' 'aute' 'irure' 'dolor' 'in' 'reprehenderit' 'in' 'voluptate' 'velit' 'esse' 'cillum' 'dolore' 'eu' 'fugiat' 'nulla' 'pariatur.' 'Excepteur' 'sint' 'occaecat' 'cupidatat' 'non' 'proident,' 'sunt' 'in' 'culpa' 'qui' 'officia' 'deserunt' 'mollit' 'anim' 'id' 'est' 'laborum' 'Sed' 'ut' 'perspiciatis' 'unde' 'omnis' 'iste' 'natus' 'error' 'sit' 'voluptatem' 'accusantium' 'doloremque' 'laudantium,' 'totam' 'rem' 'aperiam,' 'eaque' 'ipsa' 'quae' 'ab' 'illo' 'inventore' 'veritatis' 'et' 'quasi' 'architecto' 'sit' 'amet,' 'consectetur' 'adipisicing' 'elit,' 'sed' 'do' 'eiusmod' 'tempor' 'incididunt' 'ut' 'labore' 'et' 'dolore' 'magna' 'aliqua.' 'Ut' 'enim' 'ad' 'minim' 'veniam,' 'quis' 'nostrud' 'exercitation' 'ullamco' 'laboris' 'nisi' 'ut' 'aliquip' 'beatae' 'vitae' 'dicta' 'sunt' 'explicabo.' 'Nemo' 'enim' 'ipsam' 'voluptatem' 'quia' 'voluptas' 'sit' 'aspernatur' 'aut' 'odit' 'aut' 'fugit,' 'sed' 'quia' 'consequuntur' 'magni' 'dolores' 'eos' 'qui' 'ratione' 'voluptatem' 'sequi' 'nesciunt.' 'Neque' 'porro' 'quisquam' 'est,' 'qui' 'dolorem' 'ipsum' 'quia' 'dolor' 'sit' 'amet,' 'consectetur,' 'adipisci' 'velit,' 'sed' 'quia' 'non' 'quaerat' 'voluptatem.' 'Ut' 'enim' 'ad' 'minima' 'veniam,' 'quis' 'nostrum' 'exercitationem' 'ullam' 'corporis' 'suscipit' 'laboriosam,' 'nisi' 'ut' 'aliquid' 'ex' 'ea' 'commodi' 'consequatur?' 'Quis' 'autem' 'vel' 'eum' 'iure' 'reprehenderit' 'qui' 'in' 'ea' 'voluptate' 'velit' 'esse' 'quam' 'nihil' 'molestiae' 'consequatur,' 'vel' 'illum' 'qui' 'dolorem' 'eum' 'fugiat' 'quo' 'voluptas' 'nulla' 'pariatur?').
```

where objCollection is guaranteed to contain all elements in srcCollection. Note: In my application objCollection are actually complex objects containing these strings as identifiers with no duplicates.

I've been measuring and trying to optimize selecting all the objects in objCollection that are also in srcCollection. The times below are in milliseconds using `[ 1000 timesRepeat: [ ... ] ] timeToRun` in Pharo 1.2 with Stack VM and Windows XP with 2Gb of memory. These are my attempts:

```
objCollection intersection: srcCollection
7537
7507

objCollection select: [: str | srcCollection includes: str ]
7471
7507

srcCollection collect: [: str | objCollection detect: [: obj | obj = str ] ]
4227
4323
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to add `asSet` to the two collections, you might do faster. I went from 1480 to 197 ms.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I forgot to mention my data set does not contain duplicates, if you meant #asSet for removing duplicates.

Comment: No, a Set uses a different data structure and is a lot faster. Just add asSet at the end of the objCollection and srcCollection definition

Comment: Only the srcCollection in your example needs to be a Set for this to be fast. Sets have 0(1) includes: implementation, while both have O(n) iterators :)

Answer (score 4):

The first two do the same thing: `Collection >> #intersection:`'s implementation is `self select: [:each | aCollection includes: each]`.

`Collection >> #intersection:` ultimately uses `self anySatisfy: [:x | x = mySearchObj ]` to do its job, which iterates through the collection using `#do:`. `#detect:` ultimately does the same thing.

I suspect the difference you're seeing's not because any of the three is more efficient than the other, but rather a product of things like garbage collection.

Given that, I'd choose `#intersection:` because of its semantic clarity. It says what you want, rather than the other two, where you only see how you get what you want and have to infer/deduce the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Both collections have duplicates.

```
srcCollection size ~= srcCollection asSet size.
objCollection size ~= objCollection asSet size.
```

If you want to handle duplicates, assuming you have a total order available via < another possibility is to use this method (cost n1*log(n1) + n2*log(n2) + n1 + n2 instead of n1*n2 for naive intersection)

```
Collection>>sortedIntersection: aCollection
    "Answer the intersection of two collections, sorted by < and accounting duplicates."
    | intersection obj objStream src srcStream |
    srcStream := self sorted readStream.
    objStream := aCollection sorted readStream.
    intersection := (Array new: self size) writeStream.
    [srcStream atEnd | objStream atEnd] whileFalse:
        [src := srcStream next.
        obj := objStream next.
        [src = obj] whileFalse:
            [[src < obj] whileTrue: [srcStream atEnd ifTrue: [^intersection contents]. src := srcStream next].
            [obj < src] whileTrue: [objStream atEnd ifTrue: [^intersection contents]. obj := objStream next]].
        intersection nextPut: src].
    ^intersection contents
```

That would also work using a Heap, and removing first element, but slowly.

```
heapSortedIntersection: aCollection
    "Answer the intersection of two collections, sorted by < and accounting duplicates."

    | intersection obj src objHeap srcHeap |
    srcHeap := Heap withAll: self.
    objHeap := Heap withAll: aCollection.
    intersection := (Array new: self size) writeStream.
    [srcHeap isEmpty | objHeap isEmpty] whileFalse:
        [src := srcHeap removeFirst.
        obj := objHeap removeFirst.
        [src = obj] whileFalse:
            [[src < obj] whileTrue: [srcHeap isEmpty ifTrue: [^intersection contents]. src := srcHeap removeFirst].
            [obj < src] whileTrue: [objHeap isEmpty ifTrue: [^intersection contents]. obj := objHeap removeFirst]].
        intersection nextPut: src].
    ^intersection contents
```

Finally, if you haven't a total order available, you can simply use a Bag, still accounting for duplicates

```
bagIntersection: aCollection
    "Answer the intersection of two collections, accounting duplicates."

    | objBag absentTag |
    objBag := Bag withAll: aCollection.
    absentTag := Object new.
    ^self reject: [:each | (objBag remove: each ifAbsent: [absentTag]) == absentTag]
```